# Define target name in other recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

It may be ugly but I'd like to use a macro in a target name which gets a value assigned in another recipe. I know how to define macros/variables in other recipes with the eval function like this:

```
read :
  $(eval TEXT := $(shell cat somefile.txt))
say : read
  echo ${TEXT}
```

It would result in:

```
$ make say
what ever's in this file
```

That's fine. Also one can use Macros to define target names. Now let's say I have a file, for example a tar ball, the name of which always starts with 'program-' and ends whith '.bar' and in between is the version which is located in a separate file, e.g. 'program-1.2.3.tar' . So in principle I could define the target for this file with:

```
VERSION = $(shell cat version.txt)
program-${VERSION}.tar :
  tar cf program-${VERSION}.tar program-${VERSION}
```

Alright, this also works fine. But actually I want to read this file only in a target, e.g.:

```
.PHONY : getversion
getversion :
  $(eval VERSION := $(shell cat version.txt))
program-${VERSION}.tar : gerversion
  tar cf program-${VERSION}.tar program-${VERSION}
```

but of course this doesn't work since make already determines the target name by invoking make in the first place. Is there some way to solve this weird problem without having an extra makefile?

Comment: So you have $(VERSION) evaluate also to something different? I don't completely grok your problem, sorry. Maybe you can tell us the relation of the different version numbers to your build process - circumventing the original problem seems better than trying to run against the basic logic of make. BTW you can also read a file with $(file < version.txt) which saves you a shell invocation.

Comment: Yep, ${VERSION} will be something fetched from the network that's why I want to evaluate it only when it's necessary. But I think there's no way to do something like that.

Comment: But $(VERSION) _is always_ necessary, otherwise you don't know how to continue with your build, no? Where would the time saving come from, when you evaluate "only when its necessary"?

Comment: sorry for the late answer, was quite busy in the past few weeks.
And no it's not always necessary for completely different targets in the same file that's why i wanted to avoid it. I think I've to live with it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to evaluate **VERSION** and **TAR_VERSION** outside out the targets. To set `TAR_VERSION` as the target name, you should also add it to `.PHONY` target. The whole thing can be like this,

```
.PHONY : getversion $(TAR_VERSION)

VERSION := $(shell cat version.txt)
TAR_VERSION := $(addprefix program-, $(addsuffix .tar, ${VERSION}))

getversion :
  echo ${VERSION}
$(TAR_VERSION) :
  tar cf ${TAR_VERSION} program-${VERSION}
```

Comment: You're right, that's what I did before. But getting the file with the version takes some time so I really only want do run it inside another recipe. Thanks so far.

Comment: Before you evaluate `VERSION`, there's no way we can get the target name `program-${VERSION}.tar`. I don't think you can pass the `${VERSION}` from another target.

Comment: I already feared so. I think I have to find another way around it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your problem in all nuances, but I think you are seeing this more complicated than it really is. As far as your description can be understood, you have the following makefile, which you use to `make this` and `make that`, where the former is a target which is not dependant on the program-x.y.z.tar and only the latter asks over a slow connection which version you are actually dealing with:

```
.PHONY : this that getversion

this:
    @echo etc....

that: program-${VERSION}.tar
    @echo done with program-${VERSION}

getversion :
  $(eval VERSION := $(shell cat version.txt))

program-${VERSION}.tar : getversion
  tar cf program-${VERSION}.tar program-${VERSION}
```

This however is your dependencies misunderstood, if I may say this. The build of `that` is never dependant on the specific version, only on the pure act of accessing version.txt. You also couldn't sensibly build one specific program-${VERSION}.tar (by passing it as the target on the command line) as you aren't able to specifiy which version, because this piece of information comes from the network. All this hints very strongly to the conclusion, that there isn't a dependency involved between `that` and `program-${VERSION}` which simplifies the makefile to:

```
.PHONY : this that getversion

this:
    @echo etc....

that: getversion
    @echo done with program-${VERSION}

getversion:
  $(eval VERSION := $(file < version.txt))
  tar cf program-${VERSION}.tar program-${VERSION}
```